# openshift ssh access denied

Tags: ssh, openshift

If I try to ssh or git push to openshift, I get the error "access not allowed". The SSH public key is listed on openshift and matches the key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  Linux Mint 17.

```
dick@dick1 ~ $ ssh-keygen -l
Enter file in which the key is (/home/dick/.ssh/id_rsa): 
2048 70:f1:92:9d:d8:7b:09:4c:8e:7d:60:94:53:a0:7a:8a  OpenShift-Key (RSA)
dick@dick1 ~ $ rhc sshkey list
default (type: ssh-rsa)
-----------------------
  Fingerprint: 70:f1:92:9d:d8:7b:09:4c:8e:7d:60:94:53:a0:7a:8a
  Available:   true

You have 1 SSH keys associated with your account.
dick@dick1 ~ $ cd /c/src/time
dick@dick1 /c/src/time $ git push
ssh: connect to host time-cronos.rhcloud.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
dick@dick1 /c/src/time $ ssh time-cronos.rhcloud.com
ssh: connect to host time-cronos.rhcloud.com port 22: Connection timed out
dick@dick1 /c/src/time $
```

Comment: Sorry, where is this "access not allowed" error? I don't see it anywhere in your sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe port 22 is blocked where you are? Can you telnet to port 22 at time-cronos.rhcloud.com?  If not it might be time to involve your systems administrator or try from another location.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that port 22 is blocked as the connection times out, I would suggest running an nmap scan in order to get more information regarding the port state provided that you have permission to port scan the server:

> nmap -p 22 --reason -sT time-cronos.rhcloud.com